# Sending a response back when a chain of actors are involved in Spray

Tags: scala, rest, akka, actor, spray

I'm implementing a REST endpoint in Spray.

Here is the flow along with the name of the actors that are responsible for each of the step below.

1. Invoke the REST API and pass the required parameters (ActorSupervisor)
2. Validate the parameters (ValidateActor)
3. Call an external datastore to get data based on the parameter values (DataStoreActor) 
   3a. The external datastore API returns a `Future`
4. Pass the `Future` in step 3a. to an actor that can process the data (ProcessingActor)
5. Returned the processing results back to the client (as Future[ HTTP Response])

The most expensive step is #4 (which may take anywhere from a 400ms to 5 minutes depending on the size of the input dataset.

My question is how can I return a HTTP response back from #5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle that which you can use which gels well with your architecture. Using any method, you will have to use ctx's (spray's RequestContext) complete method to complete the HTTP request. You can use:-

1. Pass "ctx" (spray's RequestContext) encapsulated in the Actor's message and utilize ctx in the Step #5 to complete the request. 
   For example:-
   If currently, you pass `message` from ActorStep1 to ActorStep2 then you will need to pass `message(ctx)`
   in this method. The benefit in this method is that you can complete the request from any step but an extra attribute will be added to each message.
2. Instead of `telling` you can use `ask` pattern. In the step 5, you will respond back to Actor in step 4 with `Future[ HTTP Response]`. Similarly, Actor in step 4 will respond to Actor in step 3 and so on. This works for me because I have only one chain, may not work for you.
3. You can use `forward` pattern. For example - Actor in step 1 will pass a message to Actor in Step 2. The Actor in Step 2 will `forward` the message to Actor in Step 3 after processing and so on till Actor in Step 5. The actor in Step 5 will respond back using `sender ! Future[HTTPResponse]` which will actually send the message to Actor in Step 1 where you can complete the request.

Spray is just a thin layer on top of Akka, treat this as a case of passing a message back to parent Actor from child actor.

Comment: I think #1 is the best option for my use case. I may try #3 as well. I believe for #2 you need to block (.await) inside each actor. correct?

Comment: Yes, for #2, the thread will be blocked. I use partially #1 and #2 based on the scenario. One more way is to directly get access to the first actor using `actorOf` method of ActorRefFactory and then send message directly to it.